# Strange black borders around buttons in toolbar after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: upgrade, nautilus, do-release-upgrade, 17.04

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04. Everything seemed fine until I opened the file manager. There are strange black borders around the buttons at the upper left corner, and the folders also seem to be much closer to each other. I don't know if this is a problem in Ubuntu 17.04 or if something went wrong while upgrading. How can I fix this?

I have an AMD graphics card.

**Edit #1:** I noticed that those strange borders are not only in the file explorer, they are also around the search bar in the settings app and I think it something wrong with unity.

[image: Strange Black Borders around the button in the file manager]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

[image: The borders around the search bar]

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your screenshot.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Look at the black borders around the back button at the upper left corner!

Comment: Not likely to be the infamous bug, different symptom (if this is symptom at all, I still can't see anything wrong with it). The symptom of the Nvidia bug affects window dressing only.

Comment: @CelticWarrior The buttons shouldn't look like this, take a look at [http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-_fdof7zfrvQ/VDz-UmxPAoI/AAAAAAAAUj0/NzoHMbwtDhE/s1600/radiance-gnome312.png] also notice how the folders are much closer in my screenshot, they was not like this before the upgrade.